# Warning on "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas

I was doing a study case for my assignment on World Aid and how we as programmers should handle the problem. So I was running this code which cuts out the outliers.

```
percentiles = data_help['exports'].quantile([0.05,0.95]).values
data_help['exports'][data_help['exports'] <= percentiles[0]] = percentiles[0]
data_help['exports'][data_help['exports'] >= percentiles[1]] = percentiles[1]
```

When I run this code it returns the error as

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I did not encounter this problem when I was using my friends computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc`:

```
percentiles = data_help['exports'].quantile([0.05,0.95]).values
data_help.loc[data_help['exports'] <= percentiles[0], 'exports'] = percentiles[0]
data_help.loc[data_help['exports'] >= percentiles[1], 'exports'] = percentiles[1]
```

Read: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15239951)